# Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME") produces different results when run from Rstudio console and Terminal

Tags: java, r, rstudio

When run from Rstudio console, `Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")` produces `"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"`. However, the same command yields `"/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8"` when run from Rstudio terminal.

`whereis java -b` shows that both the java-8 and jdk-11 are on the path variable as shown below,

`java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/share/java /opt/jdk1.8.0_73/bin/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin/java`

`update-alternatives --config java` shows that the selected default java is jdk11,

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0         /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
   1         /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
 * 2         /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin/java          1         manual mode
```

can anyone kindly explain what could be the reason for getting very different outputs?

Comment: when you are opening a terminal or Rstudio console, maybe you are sourcing a release? This can happen on linux but i am not sure if Rstudio console has any file such as .bashrc . Maybe you can check this?

Comment: Hey you, once it happened to me that I had Intellij open and while that, i changed the JAVA_HOME path. I had two different results, as well. I just needed to close Intellij again. A  reboot might help, too.